# Integer programming cuttings plane: code to find and explain strong cuts

Tags: inequality, optimization, discrete-optimization, integer-programming, python

My question has to do with integer programming and having a code that helps a researcher derive cutting planes.

Has anyone written some code, potentially interactive, to generate and explain cutting planes for a user or student?

I would like to see something like WolframAlpha's explanation of how to do an integral, but instead of how to derive some useful cutting planes for an integer program.

For example, I would like to run input an optimization problem
$$
\max \ \ c^\top x 
$$
$$
s.t.  Ax \leq b
 $$
$$
     x \in \{0,1\}^n
$$

- Solve the LP relaxation
- If the LP relaxation is fractional,
  --> have a solver generate some cuts that remove the fractional LP solution
  --> then have the code explain how to derive these cuts.

I think that this could be both a useful learning tool for students as well as an exploration tool for researchers.

Ideally, a user would run this on small integer programs (maybe 10 variables) to get a sense of what useful cuts for their integer program are.

Comment: Wait, what do you imagine as a benefit of such software? Other than the ability to generate arbitrarily many copies of the same course (with different examples) and hope that learners will make use of it, I bet you expect some graphics and illustrations will be the software's biggest advantage, right?

Comment: Advantages
(1) I'd like a computational tool to help with deriving facets of an integer hull.  This would help with devising general characterizations such a polytope.

(2) It would be nice to have tools to compute "rank" of certain cutting closures or "rank" of a cut with respect to a certain type of cutting plane closure.   This can help undertstand how my rounds of cuts are needed.  

I hadn't really thought about pretty graphics/illustrations to be honest.   I figure graphics are for 2d or 3d  visualization, but I'd prefer to have something that works in about 10 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Vanderbei has a Gomory Cutting Plane Tool here: https://vanderbei.princeton.edu/JAVA/pivot/gomory.html